# how to return getter for method matching a String using java reflect

Tags: java, reflection

This is my situation and i don't know if it is possible,
I need some Ideas.

I Have My MasterTable Object populated with Data

```
MasterTable MT; //already with data
```

a list for methods

```
List<String> mymethods = new ArrayList<String>();
mymethods.add("getName");
mymethods.add("getLocation");
```

and i have an array MasterTable Methods,

```
Class<MasterTable> masterclass = MasterTable.class;
Method[] masterMethods = masterclass.getMethods();
```

What i want is to loop through MasterTable methods and when i find masterMethod matching my criteria then i print value for that method.

e.g.

```
for (Method mm : masterMethods) {
if(mymethods.contains(mm.getName)){
      //print method matching MT.get Method Matching mm.getName
      System.out.println("print MT.getMethodMatchingmm.getName()");
}
}
```

Is it possible to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure!

```
if (mymethods.contains(mm.getName()) {
    Object result = mm.invoke(MT);
    // do anything with result
}
```

I've tried it the other way round, to avoid non-wanted matches of overloaded methods:

```
public static void callGetters(Object instance, String... names)
        throws Exception {
    for (String name : names) {
        Method method = instance.getClass().getMethod(name);
        System.out.println(name + ": " + method.invoke(instance));
    }
}

/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    callGetters(new MyObject(), "getName", "getLocation");
}
```

Comment: Am Running into 
 java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: wrong number of arguments

Comment: OK, then you must add your arguments to the call to invoke: mm.invoke(MT, arg1, arg2, ...); I thought, your master methods are just getter!

Comment: Yes they are getters, Its a java bean and i want to get value that was set in setter method.

Comment: Is it possible that you have overloaded methods (so methods with the same name but different arguments)? In this case, the names match, but instead of the no-arg version another one might have been taken.

Comment: Its working fine, in my list<String> i added setName instead of getName, it was my mistake